# Dynamic xml parsing and converting to csv in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-datareader

I have an XML file as below

```
<D1>

    <RECORD>
            <NODE>XT-300</NODE>
            <ST_DURATION>10</ST_DURATION>
            <DT_VAL>PBM98XX</DT_VAL>
            <ST_VAL>98987</ST_VAL>
            <EXIST>Yes</EXIST>
    </RECORD>       
    <RECORD>
            <NODE>XT-400</NODE>
            <ST_DURATION>10</ST_DURATION>
            <DT_VAL>CVB98XX</DT_VAL>
            <ST_VAL>65987</ST_VAL>
            <EXIST>Yes</EXIST>
    </RECORD>   
</D1>
```

I have used ElementTree to fetch the required attributes. As a sample code, I have read a single column.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as Xet
import pandas as pd


cols = ["NODE","ST_DURATION","DT_VAL","ST_VAL","EXIST"]
rows = []

xmlparse = Xet.parse('DEVICE1.xml')
root = xmlparse.getroot()

for i in root:
        node = i.find("NODE").text
        rows.append({"NODE": node})
df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=cols)
df.to_csv('output.csv')
```

I wish to parse the xml dynamically. Meaning, I should provide the columns in a separate config file and extract those columns dynamically in the code. I need this dynamic parsing because I have  similar structure of xml for other input xml files. Just that the column names are different. Below is the sample of second xml.

```
<D1>

    <RECORD>
            <ELEC>EL-13</ELEC>
            <VAL>10</VAL>
            <POWER>Max</POWER>
            <WIRING>2.3</WIRING>
            <ENABLED>Yes</ENABLED>
    </RECORD>       
    <RECORD>
            <ELEC>EL-14</ELEC>
            <VAL>30</VAL>
            <POWER>Max</POWER>
            <WIRING>1.1</WIRING>
            <ENABLED>Yes</ENABLED>
    </RECORD>       
</D1>
```

Updating the new xml which is required for the dynamic parsing.

```
  <D1>

<J1>
    <RECORD>
        <DATA>
            <ELEC>EL-13</ELEC>
            <VAL>10</VAL>
        </DATA>
            <POWER>Max</POWER>
            <WIRING>2.3</WIRING>
            <ENABLED>Yes</ENABLED>
    </RECORD>       
    <RECORD>
            <ELEC>EL-14</ELEC>
            <VAL>30</VAL>
            <POWER>Max</POWER>
            <WIRING>1.1</WIRING>
            <ENABLED>Yes</ENABLED>
    </RECORD>   
</J1>       
</D1>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the code provided by Nk03 to convert the XML you're loading to a python dictionary.

```
import xmltodict

d = xmltodict.parse("""
<D1>
    <RECORD>
            <ELEC>EL-13</ELEC>
            <VAL>10</VAL>
            <POWER>Max</POWER>
            <WIRING>2.3</WIRING>
            <ENABLED>Yes</ENABLED>
    </RECORD>       
    <RECORD>
            <ELEC>EL-14</ELEC>
            <VAL>30</VAL>
            <POWER>Max</POWER>
            <WIRING>1.1</WIRING>
            <ENABLED>Yes</ENABLED>
    </RECORD>       
</D1>
""")
```

From there, you can generate a list of keys to use as the column names for the DataFrame:

```
for key in parsed_dictionary.keys():
    cols.append(key)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here’s one way:

```
import xmltodict

d = xmltodict.parse("""
<D1>
    <RECORD>
            <ELEC>EL-13</ELEC>
            <VAL>10</VAL>
            <POWER>Max</POWER>
            <WIRING>2.3</WIRING>
            <ENABLED>Yes</ENABLED>
    </RECORD>       
    <RECORD>
            <ELEC>EL-14</ELEC>
            <VAL>30</VAL>
            <POWER>Max</POWER>
            <WIRING>1.1</WIRING>
            <ENABLED>Yes</ENABLED>
    </RECORD>       
</D1>
""")

pd.DataFrame(d).iloc[:,0].explode().apply(pd.Series).reset_index(drop=True).to_csv('out.csv’)

# Alternative:
pd.json_normalize(d).stack().explode().apply(pd.Series)
```

Explanation ->

1. Convert the XML to dict.
2. load the result into a dataframe.
3. use explode to extract the values from the list of dict into multiple roes.
4. Apply `pd.series` to generate the required columns from the `dict`
5. Save the output to `csv`.

Updated Answer:

```
df1 = pd.json_normalize(d).stack().explode().apply(pd.Series)
pd.concat([df1.pop('DATA').apply(pd.Series), df1], 1)
```

Comment: Can you  please explain the working of pd.DataFrame(d['D1']).iloc[:, 0].apply(pd.Series).to_csv('out.csv')

Comment: Here in the code , we have hardcoded "D1" in pd.DataFrame(d['D1']).iloc[:, 0].apply(pd.Series).to_csv('out.csv'). Can this be eleminated so that if the value is say "F1" or anything, even then this code should parse them

Comment: @stacktesting updated answer. iloc is used to pick the 1st column

Comment: I see that , If I add an additional tag after <D1> , lets say <DATA> and then the <RECORD> which is already there. This approach is failing. How can we process it based on the X PATH

Comment: Added one alternative but It’ll be helpful if you can add the updated `XML`

Comment: I have updated the new xml. Please refer to the latest xml which has the tag "J1" and "DATA" in it

Comment: @stacktesting you've got a highly `nested dict` better solution is `recursive approach`, but I've added one `temp solution`.